# TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep getting error when going back in a page:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
    at Object.Pb.$$parse (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:86:140)
    at chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:90:313
    at k.$eval (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:111:353)
    at k.$digest (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:108:419)
    at chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:90:426
    at chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:38:222
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:280)
    at f (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:38:205)
    at chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:31:225
```

Currently creating a chrome extension with angularjs being embedded into the page. My content.js file:

```
'use strict';
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if ( window.location.host.match(/(stack|gmail|shopify|magento|zendesk|desk.com|)/) ){
        // load the app from all the other dependancies
        var app = angular.module('joggle_ecommerce', [
                "joggle_ecommerce.controllers",
                "joggle_ecommerce.services",
                "joggle_ecommerce.directives"
            ])
        .config(function($locationProvider) {
            // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        })

        // find the html and add the angular needed directives
        var html = document.querySelector('html');
        html.setAttribute('ng-app', '');
        html.setAttribute('ng-csp', '');





        // bootstrap due to angular needing to load after page load
        angular.bootstrap(html, ['joggle_ecommerce'], []);
    }

})
```

When I remove `angular.bootstrap(html, ['joggle_ecommerce'], []);`, this problem does not persist but from my knowledge I need to include the bootstrap with the extension because angular needs to load after page load.

Comment: `angular.bootstrap` with third empty array – are you missing config object?